# Histogram of 3D-orientations in python/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, scipy, histogram

I have a dataset containing a large amount of (weighted) orientations. I want to make a nice representation to test/visualize whether there are clusters of orientation in certain directions.

First I made three 2D polar plots: I threw one dimension away and plot a 'windrose', showing in which directions the orientations are directed in the remaining two dimensions. This seems to work quite nicely: there are one or two clusters of orientations in two of these surfaces. The data is however 3D and I want to see where clusters of orientations are pointing in all these three dimensions.

In 3D, however, the problem gets much harder. My first guess was to make a 'two-dimensional' polar plot, combining the two angles in two surfaces (inclination and azimuth) and show this as an image. Now, however, some bins represent a much larger area of surface on the sphere of orientation than others (I think this is called polar singularity).

I have found this older thread about this problem in Matlab: http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/236925, but there isn't really a straightforward solution there: first of all I'd rather not work with matlab, but Python/Scipy, secondly, I don't have a licence for this toolbox, and thirdly I rather have code of which I know what is does.

Anyone has any ideas for alternative solutions and/or a way to do this in Python/Num-/Scipy?
Is there a nice way to lay a 2D grid over a sphere of similar-sized-bins?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a solution to "lay a 2Dgrid over a sphere of similar sized bins" because I'm not really sure what you mean by that but I think it might be good to visualize your data.

If you can take your orientation data (a list a 3D vectors) and normalize it then this might do the job :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

orientation = np.random.random((3,50))
weight = np.random.randint(100, size=50)

ax.scatter(orientation[0], orientation[1], zs= orientation[2], s=weight)
plt.show()
```

it will plot point representing the normalized orientation vectors and of the size of the weight assiociated to each orientation.

Alternatively and more complex but more in line with your initial idea there is this snippet from the matplotlib 3D plot tutorial :

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

plt.show()
```

All you need is to compute a color map which is an array reprensenting the weighted density of orientation present in each subdivision of the plot and pass it as the color kwarg.
(I'll look into that tomorrow but that should get you started)